# Tokenfield for Bootstrap can not catch event when delete a token

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-tokenfield

I can't catch delete token event by press "delete" on keyboard when using Tokenfield for Bootstrap.

I only can catch delete event by click ".close"

Please see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rns3hang/17/).

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
    $('#tokenfield').tokenfield({
      autocomplete: {
        source: ['red','blue','green','yellow','violet','brown','purple','black','white'],
        delay: 100
      },
      showAutocompleteOnFocus: true
    });

    $("form").submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.form-data').text( $('#tokenfield').val());
    });
    close();


});

function close() {

    $(document).on('click', 'a.close', function(){
         alert('delete');
        });

}

$('input').change(function() {
close();
})
```

Comment: Do you mean when you have the focus on one of the tags that you can't delete it by pressing the `delete` key?  I am able to do that in your fiddle.

Comment: i can delete it but can not catch the delete event by pressing the delete key.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#tokenfield').on('tokenfield:removedtoken', function (event) {
    alert('delete');
});
```

Info: http://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/#events

It will catch the remove token event. This listener in particular is triggered after the removal.